# Tikz: How to reference "lower s.east" in a cylinder?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I try to stack multiple cylinders in a tikz graphic. To do this I need the lower s.east-position (see image):

[image]

How can I reference the coordinate?

In my actual solution (a graphical recipe for a cocktail) I tried a solution  with offsets, but it needs always a adaption, when I adapt anything.

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames}{xcolor}
\documentclass[tikz,margin=2mm]{standalone}
  \usetikzlibrary{calc}
  \usetikzlibrary{positioning}%%right =of node_x
  \usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
  \usetikzlibrary{patterns.meta}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance=20mm and 20mm,%%y-x-distance
    tumbler/.style={draw,text centered,cylinder,shape border rotate=90,aspect=0.25,text width=50mm},
    tumblercontent/.style={tumbler,opacity=.6,anchor=south},
    circled/.style={shape=circle,draw,inner sep=2pt,double},%%for number in a circle
  ]
  \node[tumbler,minimum height =100mm,label={Peach Fizz}] (tumbler) {};
  \node[tumblercontent,fill=Peach,minimum height =20mm] at (tumbler.south) (peach) {2cl Peach sirup};
  \node[tumblercontent,fill=yellow,minimum height =20mm] at ($ (peach.top) - (0,13mm) $) (lemon) {2cl Lemon juice};
  \node[tumblercontent,fill=black!05,minimum height =40mm] at ($ (lemon.top) - (0,13mm) $)  (gin) {4cl Gin};
  \node[tumblercontent,fill=black!05,minimum height =50mm,pattern={Dots[distance=10pt,angle=45]}] at ($ (gin.top) - (0,13mm) $)  (soda) {Soda};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(the 4-6 ice cubes are missing in my graphic :-) )

Comment: Unrelated `($ (peach.top) - (0,13mm) $)` is the same as `([yshift=-13mm] peach.top)` (no need for `calc`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the side anchors instead:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames}{xcolor}
\documentclass[tikz,margin=2mm]{standalone}
  \usetikzlibrary {shapes.symbols}
  \usetikzlibrary{positioning}%%right =of node_x
  \usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
  \usetikzlibrary{patterns.meta}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance=20mm and 20mm,%%y-x-distance
    tumbler/.style={draw,text centered,cylinder,shape border rotate=90,aspect=0.25,text width=50mm},
    tumblercontent/.style={tumbler,opacity=.6,anchor=south},
    circled/.style={shape=circle,draw,inner sep=2pt,double},%%for number in a circle
  ]
  \foreach \i in {1,...,10}
\node[blue!80!white, thick, fill=blue!20!white, opacity=0.4, cloud, draw, cloud puffs=4, cloud puff arc=80, minimum width=1.8cm, minimum height=1.5cm, rotate=20*rand] at ((1.5*rand,4+0.4*rand) {};
  \node[tumbler,minimum height =100mm,label={Peach Fizz}] (tumbler) {};
  \node[tumblercontent,fill=Peach,minimum height =20mm] at (tumbler.south) (peach) {2cl Peach sirup};
  \node[tumblercontent,fill=yellow,minimum height =20mm, anchor=after bottom] at (peach.before top) (lemon) {2cl Lemon juice};
  \node[tumblercontent,fill=black!05,minimum height =40mm, anchor=after bottom] at (lemon.before top) (gin) {4cl Gin};
  \node[tumblercontent,fill=black!05,minimum height =50mm,pattern={Dots[distance=10pt,angle=45]}, anchor=after bottom] at (gin.before top) (soda) {Soda}; 
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Drink with icecubes]

Comment: Nice idea! I change the style `tumblercontent/.style={tumbler,opacity=.6,anchor=after bottom},` and  change the anchor to `south` for the first ingrediant (peach). And thanks for the ice cubes!

Answer (score 2):

Here a new anchor `end` for shape `cylinder` is provided:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\makeatletter
\begingroup
% new anchor `end` for shape `cylinder`
\def\pgf@sm@shape@name{cylinder}

% the same as `\pgfdeclareshape{cylinder}{... \anchor{end top} ...}
\pgf@sh@anchor{end}{%
  \getcylinderpoints
  \pgfmathrotatepointaround{%
    \pgfpointadd{%
      \beforetop
      \pgf@y=0pt\relax
      \advance\pgf@x-\xradius
    }{\centerpoint}%
  }{\centerpoint}{\rotate}%
}
\endgroup
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[shape=cylinder, draw=gray!50, line width=10pt, aspect=.5, font=\huge\color{gray!50}, inner sep=1em] (s) {Cylinder\rule{.4pt}{3em}};
  
  \foreach \anchor/\placement in {
    top/above, bottom/above, end/above%
  } {
    \draw[shift=(s.\anchor), text depth=.25ex] plot[mark=x] coordinates{(0,0)}
      node[\placement] {\scriptsize\texttt{(s.\anchor)}};
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]